# Why does www.mywebsite.com/folder work, but www.mywebsite.com/folder/ does not?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Why does **mywebsite.com/page** work, but **mywebsite.com/page/** does not? We have an htaccess entry that removes the .php ending of files, for example "mywebsite.com/new.php" can be accessed simply as "mywebsite.com/new". However, if a forward slash is added (and this seems to happen with some search engines adding it or browsers for some reason) then our 404 error page is shown. Any ideas? Many thanks!

Here are all the rewriterules in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.cz [NC]
rewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.cz/$1 [R=301,L]

rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC]
rewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.com$
RewriteRule ^cs$ "http\:\/\/www\.mywebsite\.com\/index_cz\.php" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mywebsite.cz [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.mywebsite.cz [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index_cz [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite\.com
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ project.php?id=$1 [NC,L] # Handle project requests

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite\.cz
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ project_cz.php?id=$1 [NC,L] # Handle project requests
```

Comment: The portion regarding the .php removal is:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

also, you have to change all your , ,  to point to the root of the folder. eg:

```
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/charactercounter.js"></script>
```

will become:

```
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon.ico"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/charactercounter.js"></script>
```

Comment: weird, i use this rule for my site, do you have any other rewriterules in the .htaccess?

Comment: I've just edited my original post to show all the rewriterules in the .htaccess file...

Comment: can you give me an example of what you see?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5158/discussion-between-book-of-zeus-and-joew)

Answer (score 2):

when you are writing mysite.com/page, this is directing you to the document in the root directory.  However, when you write my site.com/page/ Apache will think you are references a directory named page, and then looking for a document in the page directory.

Comment: OK, any ideas how I can make the / versions direct to the un-slashed pages?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this...

```
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.yoursite\.com$ [NC]
      RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```